Tikz-Feynman: Multiple momentum arrow on longer edges
I am trying to draw a two loop vacuum diagram using Tikz-Feynman, but on longer semi circular edges two momentum arrows show on the edge instead of one long one.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-3,-5) rectangle (3,1);
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [below=4 of a](b);
    
    
    \diagram* {
        (a) -- [momentum={$q_1+q_2$}](b),
    };
    \draw [rmomentum'={$q_1$}] (a) arc (90:270:2);
    \draw [momentum'={$q_2$}] (b) arc (-90:90:2);
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

(the boundingbox is there for readability of the standalone)
Is there a way to get a single arrow on such an edge? Half turns do have only one associated arrow, but they are not perfectly circular.


Welcome to TeX.SX!

Do you really need the path to be perfectly circular?
With half key, adjusting the looseness you can achieve an almost circular shape:
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [below=4 of a](b);

    \draw [red, dashed] (a) arc (90:270:2);
    \draw [red, dashed] (b) arc (-90:90:2);

    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [momentum={$q_1+q_2$}] (b)
       --[half left, looseness=1.7, momentum={$q_1$}] (a)
       --[half left, looseness=1.7, rmomentum={$q_2$}] (b)
    };

\end{feynman}



Alternatively, you can use half left only to draw the momentums:
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [below=4 of a](b);

    \draw [] (a) arc (90:270:2);
    \draw [] (b) arc (-90:90:2);

    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [momentum={$q_1+q_2$}] (b)
       --[draw=none, half left, looseness=1.7, momentum={$q_1$}] (a)
       --[draw=none, half left, looseness=1.7, rmomentum={$q_2$}] (b)
    };

\end{feynman}


Full example:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-3,-5) rectangle (3,1);
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [below=4 of a](b);

    \draw [red, dashed] (a) arc (90:270:2);
    \draw [red, dashed] (b) arc (-90:90:2);

    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [momentum={$q_1+q_2$}] (b)
       --[half left, looseness=1.7, momentum={$q_1$}] (a)
       --[half left, looseness=1.7, rmomentum={$q_2$}] (b)
    };

\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-3,-5) rectangle (3,1);
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [below=4 of a](b);

    \draw [] (a) arc (90:270:2);
    \draw [] (b) arc (-90:90:2);

    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [momentum={$q_1+q_2$}] (b)
       --[draw=none, half left, looseness=1.7, momentum={$q_1$}] (a)
       --[draw=none, half left, looseness=1.7, rmomentum={$q_2$}] (b)
    };

\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Yes, it bothers me if the shape is not perfectly circular. Using an invisible edge to draw the arrow is a good idea, it's a lot less noticeable.
